# Android WebView - outdated browser

Tags: android, webview

So I'm working on my application and this notification came out on top of my WebView telling me that my browser is outdated. My application runs on KitKat and it work find and no such notification shows until I updated my Android Studio. So I'm not sure whether this is emulator problem, or my code problem. I've searched around for solution or the reason why this came out but there's nothing useful.

[image]

Comment: Basically this is the emulator or real device problem because this type of notification generate when your device browser setting is old version.

Comment: have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not a problem with the code. I suggest you run your app on an emulator running android lollipop or try updating Android WebView.